# Explain why the description defines a Boolean Algebra

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

This is the exercise:

> Let $A = \{a,b\}$ and list the four elements of the power set $\mathcal P(A)$. We consider the operations $+$ to be $\cup$, $\cdot$ to be $\cap$, and complement to be set complement. Consider $1$ to be $A$ and $0$ to be $\varnothing$.
>
> Explain why the description above defines a Boolean algebra.

The elements of the $\mathcal P(A) = \{\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\},\varnothing\}$.

Now I understand that in order to show that it defines a Boolean algebra, I need to show that the description meets the Boolean Algebra axioms of identity. What I don't understand, is how to show this. For example, one of the axioms is the identity axiom, which states that

$$x \cdot 1 = x$$

However, does this translate to $A \cap x = x$? and how is this true? As such, I was confused and could use some help.

Comment: Your problem statement says to treat $.$ as $\cap$ and $1$ as $A$. So $x.1 = x \cap A = x$ since $x\in A$.

Comment: so you just assume that x ∈ A?

Comment: I should have been more careful. You have $x\in P(A)$ so $x\subseteq A$ but you still have $x\cap A = x$.

Comment: so then for the complement laws, would I be correct in saying that x U x^c = A and that x∩(x^c) = ∅ and if that statement is correct? How would I explain it? x U x^c refers to all elements in x or not in x but how would that equate to A? The other statement makes sense because by set laws, x ∩ (x^c) =∅

Comment: @BobMarley the definition of "set complement" in this context is $X^{\rm c} = A\setminus X$.

Comment: @Christoph oh that clears things up, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

The Boolean algebra in this case is the power set of $A$: $\mathcal P(A)$. Thus, in any axiom for Boolean algebras, such as $x\cdot 1 = x$, the $x$ is to be taken as an element of $\mathcal P(A)$, i.e. a *subset* of $A$ (**not** an *element* of $A$).

As mentioned in the comments, another useful thing to consider is that *complement* in this case is defined relative to $A$, so that $x^c = A \setminus x$.